# In Anko, how can I give my button a coloured border?

Tags: android, kotlin, anko

I took a look at the [code](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko) but couldn't see how I can add a border to a button.  Example button that needs a border:

```
val memoryButton = button {
    backgroundColor = mainColour
    textColor = textColour
    text = "I am a button!"
    onClick {
        doSomething()
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

create file  **button_border.xml** in drawable folder like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient android:startColor="#FFFFFF"
              android:endColor="#00FF00"
              android:angle="270" />
    <corners android:radius="3dp" />
    <stroke android:width="5px" android:color="#000000" />
</shape>
```

and simply add this to background of button like this

```
button {
          text = "I am a button!"
          background=getDrawable(R.drawable.button_border)
          onClick {
              println("Hello")                     
            }
      }
```

You will get border to your button :)

Comment: Thanks. I will try that in a few hours to confirm it works.